# go get error: go tool: no such tool "compile"

Tags: go

I want to build go program from source. And it need some package from github as below.

```
➜  MEOW git:(master) ✗ go build
log.go:13:2: cannot find package "github.com/cyfdecyf/color" in any of:
    /usr/share/go-1.6/src/github.com/cyfdecyf/color (from $GOROOT)
    /home/user/gopath/src/github.com/cyfdecyf/color (from $GOPATH)
../../gopath/src/github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-go/shadowsocks/encrypt.go:16:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish" in any of:
    /usr/share/go-1.6/src/golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish (from $GOROOT)
    /home/user/gopath/src/golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish (from $GOPATH)
../../gopath/src/github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-go/shadowsocks/encrypt.go:17:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/crypto/cast5" in any of:
    /usr/share/go-1.6/src/golang.org/x/crypto/cast5 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/user/gopath/src/golang.org/x/crypto/cast5 (from $GOPATH)
../../gopath/src/github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-go/shadowsocks/encrypt.go:18:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/crypto/salsa20/salsa" in any of:
    /usr/share/go-1.6/src/golang.org/x/crypto/salsa20/salsa (from $GOROOT)
    /home/user/gopath/src/golang.org/x/crypto/salsa20/salsa (from $GOPATH)
```

I run `go get`. But get `no such tool "compile"` error.

```
➜  MEOW git:(master) ✗ go get github.com/cyfdecyf/color
go tool: no such tool "compile"
```

My system  is ubuntu 16. And I install golang from package.

```
➜  MEOW git:(master) ✗ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/usr/share/go-1.6/bin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/user/gopath"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/share/go-1.6"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/share/go-1.6/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

What should I do to get go package?

Comment: For a start I would use the latest version of Go.  1.6 is quite old now

Comment: Uninstall your totally outdated Go 1.6 and install the latest version from golang.org following their install instructions.

Comment: remove completely your folder /usr/share/go-1.6 and follow this instructions https://golang.org/doc/install